# After storing the transposed result in another matrices, it is showing incorrect result when comparing the two matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to transpose the matrix,store the transposed matrix in another matrix and compare those two matrix using for loop and list

As per the logic i was able to store the transposed result of one list in another list but i'm confused where i have gone wrong in comparison of two matrix !please assist

**code-1**

```
matrix_1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
matrix_2=[]


print(matrix_1,"\n")

for i in range(len(matrix_1[0])):
    row=[]
    for j in matrix_1:
        row.append(j[i])
    matrix_2.append(row)

print(matrix_2,"\n") 

for first in matrix_1:
    print(first)

print("\n")
for second in matrix_2:
    print(second)

print("\n")    

for row in range(0,3):
    for col in range(0,3):

        if matrix_1[row][col]==matrix_2[row][col]:
            result="It is symmetric" 
        else:
            result="It is not symmetric"
print(result)
```

**code-2**

```
matrix_1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
matrix_2=[]

sym=False
print(matrix_1,"\n")

for i in range(len(matrix_1[0])):
    row=[]
    for j in matrix_1:
        row.append(j[i])
    matrix_2.append(row)

print(matrix_2,"\n") 

for first in matrix_1:
    print(first)

print("\n")
for second in matrix_2:
    print(second)

print("\n")    

for row in range(0,3):
    for col in range(0,3):

        if matrix_1[row][col]==matrix_2[row][col]:
            sym=True 

print(sym)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second code, if any element in `matrix_1` and `matrix_2` is equal, `sym` becomes True.

You have to do it the other way round:

```
sym = True
for row in range(0,3):
    for col in range(0,3):
        if matrix_1[row][col] != matrix_2[row][col]:
            sym = False
```

Since you are only comparing lists with lists, this can be simplified to

```
sym = matrix_1 == matrix_2
```

Comment: good solution.  Also in the first coding, you are only retaining the comparison of the *last* element in the `result` variable.  So, it is passing because 9==9 in your example.  Same logic problem as explained by Daniel above.

Comment: Hello  daniel sir ,thanks for the help in the end line i tried this if statement directly it worked:

if matrix_1==matrix_2:
    print("It is symmetrical")
else:
    print("It is not symmetrical")

Comment: jeff sir please explain me the flaw in my logic in first code as im not able to understand it properly

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in your code is that you are being tripped up by the fact that your test for equality only keys on the last value.  In your original matrix and the transposed one, the last value is `9` so that is setting the `sym` variable to True, even though all the other values could be different.  See example below:

```
In [5]: list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                   

In [6]: list_2 = [3, 1, 2, 4]                                                   

In [7]: sym=False                                                               

In [8]: for i in range(len(list_1)): 
   ...:     print(i, list_1[i] == list_2[i]) 
   ...:     if list_1[i] == list_2[i]: 
   ...:         sym = True 
   ...:          
   ...:                                                                         
0 False
1 False
2 False
3 True

In [9]: print(sym)                                                              
True
```

As suggested in other solution, the better design pattern is to trigger on a mismatch, which will be retained through the loop.  Meaning once it is set once, it cannot be undone.  It can only be set to False again, which is inconsequential.  An even better (more efficient) design is to break the loop as soon as a mismatch is found, but that isn't required.  Something like this:

```
In [10]: sym = True                                                             

In [11]: for i in range(len(list_1)): 
    ...:     print(i, list_1[i]==list_2[i]) 
    ...:     if list_1[i] != list_2[i]: 
    ...:         sym = False 
    ...:         break 
    ...:                                                                        
0 False

In [12]: print(sym)                                                             
False
```